# Is it possible to use Facebook iOS sdk for develop Mac OSX application?

Tags: xcode, facebook, macos, cocoa, facebook-graph-api

I am new for Facebook Developer. I want to Create Mac OSX application using Facebook OAuth. But i can't find any Facebook SDK for Mac OSX. So is it possible to use Facebook iOS SDK to develop Mac OSX application? If can how can i do that? If not, are there any other solution to use Facebook for Create Mac OSX application..?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

In the [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) guide it states (last section of the page):

> **Windows, OS X and Linux native apps**
>
> Our OAuth 2.0 implementation does not include explicit support for
>   application built for desktop operating systems. However, if your app
>   can embed a web browser (most desktop frameworks such as .NET, AIR and
>   Cocoa support embedding browsers), you can use the client-side flow
>   with one modification: a specific redirect_uri. Rather than requiring
>   desktop apps to host a web server and populate the Site URL in the App
>   Dashboard, we provide a specific URL you can use with desktop apps:
>   https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html.

After you use that method to authenticate the user you will get a user access token and you can then simply issue http requests to the graph api.